# How can we include 'SelectALL' and 'DeselectALL' button in dynamic DT - R Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want to have 'SelectALL' checkbox button on the top of the Dynamic Data table. Once I select the checkbox then all the rows in the table should get selected and when I deselect the checkbox then all the rows should get unselected.

I used the below code to pre-select all rows in the dynamic DT but this is not what I want. I want to have a button at the top instead -

Server.R

```
library(shiny)

all_rows <- reactive({
                df <- tablefinal1()  
                  if (is.null(df)) {


return(seq_len(0))

} else { 
 return(seq_len(nrow(df)))
} 
}) 

output$table<-DT::renderDataTable({datatable(tablefinal1(),options = 
list(scrollX = TRUE ,bInfo=F,bPaginate=F,sScrollY='25vh', scrollCollapse = 
TRUE, aoColumnDefs = list(list(sClass="alignright")),buttons=c("Select 
All","Deselect 
ALL")),extensions=c("Select","Buttons"),rownames=FALSE,selection = 
list(mode='multiple',selected=all_rows()))})
```